# What is the difference between the View property and TableView property in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, tableview

After doing some research in apple documentation here's what I found.

In **UIViewController**, the *view* property

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *view
```

means the view that the controller manages.

and

In **UITableViewController**, the *tableView* property

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView
```

means the tableView that the controller manages.

Since **UITableViewController** is the subclass of **UIViewController**, it will inherit the *view* property. So when I'm writing codes in **UITableViewController** subclass file, there's these 2 properties that always confuses me and I'm not sure when to use it. Please explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `UITableViewController`, the `tableView` and `view` properties are the same.

Use the `tableView` property in your table view controller when you need to access the table view and make use of various `UITableView` properties and methods. Or even if you need plain old `UIView` methods.

It's fine to use the `view` property in cases where you only need `UIView` properties and methods. It's really a matter of taste which property to use in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In case of `UItableViewController` both are same but different in you have `UITableView` in the `UIViewController`then `view` property will refer to `UIViewController` and `tableview` will refer to `UITableView`. To avoid confusion always use `tableview` in case of `UITableViewController`